# Parse this string to an array of Guids or strings

Tags: arrays, sitefinity, string-conversion

I'm working with Sitefinity and when you add a custom Tags attribute to a Page it results in the following string value:

```
"[\"1f3560ca-84b9-6a87-9ce5-ff00009465c7\",\"893460ca-84b9-6a87-9ce5-ff00009465c7\"]"
```

Does anyone have a clever conversion method that can convert this string into an array of guids or strings?

I would write something that splits by , and removes the brackets... I just feel there must be a better way though but it doesn't come to mind.

Comment: How about `JSON.parse()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft [JavaScriptSerializer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx), which can help you turn a JSON string into objects.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserializedResult = serializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution...

```
string tags = "[\"1f3560ca-84b9-6a87-9ce5-ff00009465c7\",\"893460ca-84b9-6a87-9ce5-ff00009465c7\"]";
return tags
    .Replace("[", "")
    .Replace("]", "")
    .Replace(" ", "")
    .Replace("\"", "")
    .Split(',')
    .Where(t =>
    {
        Guid g;
        return Guid.TryParse(t, out g);
    }).Select(t => new Guid(t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting it to TrackedList?